# Form1_Paint event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, paint

i wonder how it works..

i have this code. it should paint pictures (Bitmap images ) on the form..constantly. but i dont know how often it is triggered. i need it to be triggered very often (at least every 1-2 seconds). i need it to send the parameters to another object that i have (Game game).. so game object will draw everything

```
   public void Form1_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        //the animation has 4 cell to draw, so the arguments are passed to the game objects instructing it to which cells to draw.
        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
        {
            game.Draw(g, animationTimerCounter);
        }
}
```

when is the event being fired?

Comment: The Paint event is raised when the control is redrawn. It passes an instance of PaintEventArgs to the method(s) that handles the Paint event.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A paint event is called when the form (or part of it) has to be redrawn, e.g. the form is moved, or another window has hidden a part of it etc.

You can force a Paint event by calling [`yourControl.Invalidate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) method.

In your case you could use for example a Timer to force a Paint with the desired frequency (e.g. every 1-2 seconds).

Comment: How do you trigger paint with every 1-2 seconds..do you call invalidate()... and put it in the timer?

Comment: @Dmitry: Add a `Timer` to your form (you can also do it using the designer) and set the `Interval` property to 1000 or 2000 ms, and enable it (`Enabled = true`). Then in the `timer1_Tick` event handler just call `this.Invalidate()`

Answer (score 1):

Paint is basically triggered as required, events that trigger paint can be examples such as (there are others):

- A form that was in front is moved
- You form resizes
- your form is restored

Is this XNA? it kinda looks like it is a similar effect. XNA is a good framework for what it looks like you're trying to do.

If you need your form to paint, you can invalidate it or tell it to paint.

Comment: i understand..so i dont need to make my own event for the event handler paint

Answer (score 0):

The Paint event is raised when the control is redrawn. [Control.Paint Event in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx)